# Connecting to an API from my localhost throws http/2 error

Tags: javascript, rest, http

I am connecting to an API. It works fine when I use Postman. But When I use the code generated from postman in my angular project ( on my localhost ) I cannot perform the requests. I get an error: `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` instead of an error code in my browser. The fetch code I use:

```
let code = params.get('code');
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Host", "login.eveonline.com");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic NThmYjljMGEwMWM5NGI1ODhkNmUzYzVlMTQ4NjYyYjQ6eVRUUzFGRTdUtZTzBNZkpCZw==");

  let body = {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code
  };

fetch("https://login.eveonline.com/v2/oauth/token", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: JSON.stringify( body )
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Have you to test this using the command line? (curl)

Comment: @Bonfire No, but I tried it with postman, that worked. I think it is a browser related thing. It may have something to do with CORS.

Comment: Have you included the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the API?

Comment: I am fairly certain that the problem is in the client scripts, as it should show an Internal Server Error or something instead... Are you requesting a large response?

Comment: It's just to get an authorization key, so the response should be small.

Comment: If so, the server might close the connection when sending a big response to the Chrome.

Comment: Would I be right to assume that you are using PHP for the back-end?

Comment: I am using angular to connect to this api. So there is no backend from my side.